# Bott-Samelson construction of a perfect Morse function on G/T

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, cohomology, morse-theory

An undergraduate student of mine is interested in writing a "senior" thesis on the topology of Lie groups. Let $G$ be a simply connected compact Lie group and $T$ a maximal torus. One way of calculating $\pi_2(G)$ and $\pi_3(G)$ proceeds via the Bott and Samelson construction of a perfect Morse function on $G/T$ (Perhaps the more standard way is via Iwasawa decompositions and the description of $G/T$ as a complex manifold, but my student says he prefers "geometry" to "algebra").

Bott and Samelson's papers are of course wonderful but aside from being rather vintage, they are research papers and they discuss a lot of applications to loop spaces, whose infinite dimensional nature I think would be intimidating for this student. I am therefore looking for a reference that I can give to my student that discusses this construction in a fairly "hands-on" and friendly fashion and has relatively complete proofs up to perhaps isolating one or two facts from Lie theory (say about the $\operatorname{Ad}$ representation or the Weyl group). Any suggestions?

Comment: Take $G$ be connected and simply-connected. From the principal $G_a$-bundle $G_a\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/G_x=\mathcal{O}_x$, where $\mathcal{O}_x$,is the coadjoint orbit


we obtain a long-exact sequence $$\ldots\rightarrow\pi_i(G_x)\rightarrow\pi_i(G)\rightarrow\pi_i(\mathcal{O}_x) \rightarrow \pi_{i-1}(G_x)\rightarrow\ldots.$$ Since $\pi_1(G)=0$ and $\pi_2(G)=0$, exactness considerations imply that $\pi_1(G_x)=\pi_2(\mathcal{O}_x)$.

Comment: Maybe Sect. 3.4    of these notes  http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse2nd.pdf     might  be more appealing to your student.  $G/T$ is a coadjoint orbit and as such  it is equipped with many perfect Morse functions.     In these notes  I also discuss special coadjoint orbits  such as Grassmannians and  flag manifolds.

Comment: @HassanJolany As I mentioned in the question, the goal is to \emph{prove} $\pi_2(G)=0$. There are of course other ways to do this, but one standard way is via using some suitable Bruhat or Morse stratification to a priori prove that $\pi_2(G/T)$ is torsion-free.

Comment: @user36931  It is known  fact from Olivier Debarre  that any smooth, complex, rationally connected projective variety is simply connected. So, because $G/T$ is rationally coonected projective variety , so $\pi_1(G/T)=e$

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thank you for the notes. This symplectic point of view is very nice and of course could be an entry point into other subjects.

Comment: @HassanJolany These facts are very classical and I'm well aware of how to prove them... the varieties all have Schubert stratifications so certainly no facts by Debarre are needed. Also one has to check something about $\pi_2$ not $\pi_1$. My goal is to explain this to an undergraduate student with no background in algebriac geometry and not much rep theory... Cheers

Comment: $G/T\cong G^{\mathbb C}/P$, so see my question long times ago, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156883/finding-the-2nd-homotopy-group-pi-2g-mathbbc-p , if it is ok, don't forget vote ;)